# Match rows from two different arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to create a list of all servers in the domain and note which ones are being backed up. I'm using a Quest plugin for the AD server list and a Veeam plugin for the back up list. The arrays being created, but I'm having trouble understanding how to compare and create the final list.

```
# Get list of all servers in AD

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
}
$servers = get-qadcomputer -SizeLimit 0 | where {$_.OSName -match "Server"}

$arrAllServers = @()

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $singleserver = New-Object PSObject
    $singleserver | Add-Member -Name "Name" -Value $x.name -MemberType NoteProperty
    $arrAllServers += $singleserver
}

# Get list of servers being backed up

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name VeeamPSSnapin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
}

Connect-VBRServer -Server host.foo.org -Port 9392

$allDetails = @()

$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}

# Loop through each job adding details to array
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
    $Object = Get-VBRJobObject -Job $job 
    $jobOptions = New-Object PSObject
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -value $job.name
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -value $job.isscheduleenabled
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Servers" -Value (@($Object.name) | Out-String).Trim()
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Backup Mode" -value $job.backuptargetoptions.algorithm
    $repo = (Get-VBRBackupRepository | ?{$_.HostId -eq $job.TargetHostId -and $_.Path -eq $job.TargetDir}).name
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Repository" -value $repo
    $allBackupDetails += $jobOptions
}
Disconnect-VBRServer

# Now match by server name and produce some output. 

foreach ($lserver in $arrAllServers) {
    foreach ($bserver in $allDetails) {
        if($lserver.name -eq $bserver.servers) {
            Write-Host $lserver.name $bserver.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a small sample of data so we can see the relationship of the raw data and your expected output? I see `Group-Object` being used here.

Comment: '$arrAllServers = #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name
SRIPRVNCTX1
SRIPRVNCTX2
SRIPRVNCTX3
FRCDC1
ITALDC01
FRCAPP
SRICA
srirqctx1
SRISCCM
SRINT4
SRINTERC2OLD
SRINTERC2
SRIFS01
SRINT5
SRIEX7CAS
SRINT30
SRIEX7MBX
FRCEXSERV
SRIVCENT
SRIADTS
ECSTSTCS
SRINT134
sriwatsonsam
ESGServer
HPVMEXC
SRIDOCAPP
SRIERCFS1'
... 237 items

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: $allBackupDetails = #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject    
Name Enabled Servers Backup Mode Repository
9 PM Weekday SRINT7 TRUE srint7 Increment SRIDD620/veeam
1 AM Daily QA TRUE "sriqaappprd
sriqacsprd
sriqasqlprd" Increment SRIDD620/veeam
    ... 43 items long

Comment: Very sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Trying this again. The array of servers is a single column, 237 rows:      Name
    SRIPRVNCTX1
    SRIPRVNCTX2
    SRIPRVNCTX3
    FRCDC1
    ITALDC01
    FRCAPP
    SRICA

Comment: Edit the question, use code blocks and use dummy data (but keep the style/format ofc)

Comment: The array of backup jobs has five columns and is 43 items:   Name Enabled Servers Backup Mode Repository
9 PM Weekday SRINT7 TRUE srint7 Increment SRIDD620/veeam
1 AM Daily QA TRUE "sriqaappprd
sriqacsprd
sriqasqlprd" Increment SRIDD620/veeam
2 AM Weekday SRIGLP1 TRUE sriglp1 Increment SRIDD620/veeam

Comment: I suck. I'm trying to use code blocks but evidently can't do it right. 4 spaces right?

Comment: Edit the QUESTION. Not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. You create the array `$allDetails` and read from it, but you write the objects to `$allBackupDetails`
2. `$bserver.servers` is an array so you need to use `-contains` or `-in`
3. `$bserver.servers` might be "broken" because of your `out-string`-operation (why use it?)
4. `$arrAllServers` is wasted resources when you only want the servername.

Try:

```
# Load modules

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
}

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name VeeamPSSnapin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
}

# Get list of all servers in AD
$servers = get-qadcomputer -SizeLimit 0 | where {$_.OSName -match "Server"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Get backup jobs
Connect-VBRServer -Server host.foo.org -Port 9392

$allBackupDetails = @()

$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}

# Loop through each job adding details to array
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
    $Object = Get-VBRJobObject -Job $job 
    $jobOptions = New-Object PSObject
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -value $job.name
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -value $job.isscheduleenabled
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Servers" -Value @($Object.name)
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Backup Mode" -value $job.backuptargetoptions.algorithm
    $repo = (Get-VBRBackupRepository | ?{$_.HostId -eq $job.TargetHostId -and $_.Path -eq $job.TargetDir}).name
    $jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Repository" -value $repo
    $allBackupDetails += $jobOptions
}
Disconnect-VBRServer

# Now match by server name and produce some output. 

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    foreach ($backupDetails in $allBackupDetails) {
        if($backupDetails.servers -contains $server) {
            Write-Host "$server is in $($backupDetails.name)"
        }
    }
}
```